# PHP-FPM With Opcache tries to open other pool's cached files

Tags: php, nginx, joomla, opcache

I found something strange running Joomla websites, when OpCache is enabled.

All websites have separate fpm pool, with open_base_dir restrictions.

Let's assume two webs:

```
/var/www/web1

/var/www/web2
```

First load web1 in browser, works fine.

Then I try to open the web2 and it throws open_base_dir restriction error, file_exist() cannot check /var/www/web1/....php

web2 wants to open a file from web1.

The error works on the opposite direction, I restart php-fpm, first open web2, and then web1, now the web1 wants to open a /var/www/web2 file.

That only occurs when there are two Joomlas with the same versions, and Opcache is enabled.

Somehow the opcache remembers that a script has been opened and cached and tries to load it from the other pool's directory.

I have php-fpm - 5.6.7+dfsg-1 version.

I've turned off opcache for now, but am I configured something wrong, or that's normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is  a [known issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69090) with PHP-FPM and opcache.  Amazingly, you'll be able to read the sensitive scripts regardless of ownership and permission. See [this example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04).  There isn't any way to work around it using open_base_dir restrictions or chroot.